# ListPreference instead of spinner

Tags: android

i have three spinners that contains list with values 
i want to replace the spinners with List preference

here is my spinners class

```
public static final int spinner1_op_val = 50;
public static final int spinner2_op_val = 10;
public static final int spinner3_op_val = 50;

  Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayList<Integer> spinner1_options = new ArrayList<>();
    for (i = 0; i <= spinner1_op_val; i += 1) {
        spinner1_options.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> dataAdapter_for_spinner1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinner1_options);
    dataAdapter_for_spinner1.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter_for_spinner1);
    spinner1.setSelection(4);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);





    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayList<Integer> spinner2_options = new ArrayList<>();
    for (i = 0; i <= spinner2_op_val; i++) {
        spinner2_options.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> dataAdapter_for_spinner2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spinner2_options);
    dataAdapter_for_spinner2.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setSelection(2);
    spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter_for_spinner2);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



    Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    ArrayList<Integer> spinner3_option = new ArrayList<>();
    for (i = 0; i <= spinner3_op_val; i += 5) {
        spinner3_option.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> dataAdapter_for_spinner3 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinner3_option);
    dataAdapter_for_spinner3.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner3.setAdapter(dataAdapter_for_spinner3);
    spinner3.setSelection(2);
    spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

and this is my activity that implements OnItemSelectedListener

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Editor editor;
    switch (parent.getId()) {
        case R.id.spinner1 /*2131492981*/:
            myServer.counter1 = Integer.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
            editor.putInt("counter1", myServer.counter1);
            editor.apply();
            return;
        case R.id.spinner2 /*2131492983*/:
            myServer.counter2 = (long) (Integer.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()) * 1000);
            editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
            editor.putLong("counter2", myServer.counter2);
            editor.apply();
            return;
        case R.id.spinner3 /*2131492985*/:
            myServer.counter3 = (long) (Integer.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()) * 1000);
            editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
            editor.putLong("counter3", myServer.counter3);
            editor.apply();
            return;
        default:
            return;

    }

}
```

i want to do the same thing but with List  Preference

extra text to post the question
extra text to post the question
extra text to post the question
extra text to post the question
extra text to post the question

Comment: Where your question? You can't save preference?

Comment: i want to use List Preference instead Sipnner